# Programming HEX using MPLAB X IPE v6.15, leads to PIC not starting

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, mplab-c18

When programming my PIC18F6722 using MPLAB IDE v8.91 (the 32bit version), my PIC works and starts successfully, but when I use the HEX generated from MPLAB IDE, but program it using MPLAB X IPE, the programming part is successful, but my PIC does not start up.

Comment: Are you leaving the programmer connected to the circuit after programming?  Possibly you just have the "Hold in Reset" option enabled in IPE.

Comment: I have the "Release from Reset" option enabled. I also tried to reset it by hand,

Comment: So i compared two HEXs, using the read function in **MPLAB IPE** and then by exporting the HEXs, one from a successful PIC and the other from a failed PIC, and the only difference I see is in the line number 8196.

Good PIC : 0E0000000006001BF3808000FFC0FFE0FF4001                                                  ,                Bad PIC :    0E00000000071F1BF3818500FFC0FFE0FF40DB

Comment: What you are looking at seem to be differences in how the EEPROM is initialized. So the question is "Can the code hang if the EEPROM has different settings?"

Comment: your comment helped me realize that the configurations bits we not properly set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug resolved. The issue was that MPLAB IPE was overwriting my configuration bits.. I only had to change the configuration bits in MPLAB IPE, to correspond to the ones already set in MPLAB IDE v8 (they were set via the code)

Comparing HEXs from both a successful PIC and a failed PIC told me that the issue was in the configuration bits (with the help of other people on the internet)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are programming a HEX file that will only run in a debug session invoked from the MPLABX IDE.

When programming a device using the MPLABX IPE only a HEX file built to run without debug will work.

For MPLABX v6.15 Microchip, in their infinite and near God like wisdom, changed the default action for the build icons on the tool ribbon to do a debug build.

Now to do a release build open the icon option list and select the second choice.

Incremental build:
[image: Incremental build]

Clean and build:
[image: Clean and build]

Comment: I wasn't too clear in my question, i'm using **MPLAB IDE v8.91** and trying to make my HEX generated by the same IDE, in the new **MPLAB X IPE**, I tried to change the build option to release, same issue